# Помогите, пожалуйста, написать простой сайт на js

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать сайт для нахождения пересечения двух множеств элементов. Отображаются исходные массивы, а найденные элементы выделяются цветом

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто!

> Как уж там раскрасить - на ваш выбор

```
(function() {
    const set1 = new Set([1,2,3]);
    const set2 = new Set([2,3,4]);
    const intersection = new Set([...set1].filter(x => set2.has(x)));
    console.log(Array.from(intersection)); // [2,3]
})();
```